# Unity and AdMob [Google Ads] demo don't show ADS

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I have a trouble about Google Ads since a week.
I download admob plugin from googleads/googleads-mobile-unity

Ver: 3.0.4

then opened I import package and implement demo script below:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler : IDefaultInAppPurchaseProcessor
{
    private readonly string[] validSkus = { "android.test.purchased" };

    //Will only be sent on a success.
    public void ProcessCompletedInAppPurchase(IInAppPurchaseResult result)
    {
        result.FinishPurchase();
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.OutputMessage = "Purchase Succeeded! Credit user here.";
    }

    //Check SKU against valid SKUs.
    public bool IsValidPurchase(string sku)
    {
        foreach(string validSku in validSkus)
        {
            if (sku == validSku)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Return the app's public key.
    public string AndroidPublicKey
    {
        //In a real app, return public key instead of null.
        get { return null; }
    }
}

// Example script showing how to invoke the Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin.
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
    private float deltaTime = 0.0f;
    private static string outputMessage = "";

    public static string OutputMessage
    {
        set { outputMessage = value; }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // RewardBasedVideoAd is a singleton, so handlers should only be registered once.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Calculate simple moving average for time to render screen. 0.1 factor used as smoothing
        // value.
        deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.LowerRight;
        style.fontSize = (int)(Screen.height * 0.06);
        style.normal.textColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        float fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;
        string text = string.Format("{0:0.} fps", fps);
        GUI.Label(rect, text, style);

        // Puts some basic buttons onto the screen.
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = (int)(0.03f * Screen.height);

        Rect requestBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.05f * Screen.height,
                                     0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(requestBannerRect, "Request Banner"))
        {
            RequestBanner();
        }

        Rect showBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.175f * Screen.height,
                                  0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(showBannerRect, "Show Banner"))
        {
            bannerView.Show();
        }

        Rect destroyBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.3f * Screen.height,
                                     0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(destroyBannerRect, "Destroy Banner"))
        {
            bannerView.Destroy();
        }

        Rect requestInterstitialRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.425f * Screen.height,
                                           0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(requestInterstitialRect, "Request Interstitial"))
        {
            RequestInterstitial();
        }

        Rect showInterstitialRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.55f * Screen.height,
                                        0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(showInterstitialRect, "Show Interstitial"))
        {
            ShowInterstitial();
        }
/*
        Rect requestRewardedRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.675f * Screen.height,
                                       0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(requestRewardedRect, "Request Rewarded Video"))
        {
            RequestRewardBasedVideo();
        }

        Rect showRewardedRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.8f * Screen.height,
                                    0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(showRewardedRect, "Show Rewarded Video"))
        {
            ShowRewardBasedVideo();
        }
        */
        Rect textOutputRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.925f * Screen.height,
                                  0.8f * Screen.width, 0.05f * Screen.height);
        GUI.Label(textOutputRect, outputMessage);
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-7875398596727009/9705603172";
#elif (UNITY_5 && UNITY_IOS) || UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Register for ad events.
        bannerView.OnAdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;
        bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleAdFailedToLoad;
        bannerView.OnAdLoaded += HandleAdOpened;
        bannerView.OnAdClosed += HandleAdClosed;
        bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleAdLeftApplication;
        // Load a banner ad.
        bannerView.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-7875398596727009/1543207972";
#elif (UNITY_5 && UNITY_IOS) || UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create an interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Register for ad events.
        interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
        interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
        interstitial.OnAdOpening += HandleInterstitialOpened;
        interstitial.OnAdClosed += HandleInterstitialClosed;
        interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;
        // Load an interstitial ad.
        interstitial.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
    }

    // Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
    private AdRequest createAdRequest()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
                .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
                //.AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
                //.AddKeyword("game")
                //.SetGender(Gender.Male)
                //.SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
                //.TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
                //.AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
                .Build();
    }

    private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_REWARD_BASED_VIDEO_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #elif (UNITY_5 && UNITY_IOS) || UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_REWARD_BASED_VIDEO_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(createAdRequest(), adUnitId);
    }

    private void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            print("Interstitial is not ready yet.");
        }
    }

    private void ShowRewardBasedVideo()
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        } else
        {
            print("Reward based video ad is not ready yet.");
        }
    }

    #region Banner callback handlers

    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdLoaded event received.");
    }

    public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    void HandleAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdClosing event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Interstitial callback handlers

    public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialOpened event received");
    }

    void HandleInterstitialClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialClosing event received");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion

    #region RewardBasedVideo callback handlers

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded event received.");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received for " + amount.ToString() + " " +
                type);
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

please find log form logcat below:

> Banner:  I/Ads (16645): Starting ad request.
>
> I/Ads (16645): Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("17F2B8177B4B56D0B45Z78C2D204D7BC") to
>   get test ads on this device.
>
> W/Ads (16645): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode:
>   0
>
> W/Ads (16645): Failed to load ad: 0
>
> I/Unity (16645): HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message:
>   Internal error
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType,
>   String, Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType,
>   Object, String, Object[])
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineMonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:106)
>
> I/Unity (16645):
>   GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript:HandleAdFailedToLoad(Object,
>   AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\samples\HelloWorld\Assets\GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs:253)
>
> I/Unity (16645): GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:m__8(Object,
>   AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\BannerView.cs:45)
>
> I/Unity (16645):
>   GoogleMobileAds.Android.BannerClient:onAdFailedToLoad(String) (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Android\BannerClient.cs:86)
>
> I/Unity (16645): System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object,
>   Object[], Exception&)
>
> I/Unity (16645): System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object,
>   BindingFlags, Binder, Object[
>
> E/Ads (12275): Failed to connect to
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/drt/m. No DSID retrieved.
>
> Interstitial:  I/Ads (16645): Starting ad request.
>
> I/Ads (16645): Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("17F2B8177B4B56D0B45Z78C2D204D7BC") to
>   get test ads on this device.
>
> W/Ads (16645): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode:
>   0
>
> W/Ads (16645): Failed to load ad: 0
>
> I/Unity (16645): HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad event received with
>   message: Internal error
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType,
>   String, Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType,
>   Object, String, Object[])
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>
> I/Unity (16645): UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineMonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:106)
>
> I/Unity (16645):
>   GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript:HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(Object,
>   AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\samples\HelloWorld\Assets\GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs:287)
>
> I/Unity (16645): GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd:m__12(Object,
>   AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\InterstitialAd.cs:44)
>
> I/Unity (16645):
>   GoogleMobileAds.Android.InterstitialClient:onAdFailedToLoad(String)
>   (at
>   G:\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Android\InterstitialClient.cs:99)
>
> I/Unity (16645): System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object,
>   Object[], Exception&)
>
> I/Unity (16645): System.Reflection.MonoMethod:In

in editor log suggest that script work correctly displaying logs dummy load ad ,etc. But when I built and install to my device there is no ads?!

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

I have trying it on my device Xiaomi Mi4c only because i have no access to another Android device yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with test id's first. Real ad id's don't always match.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Answer (score -1):

Download those files from Admob Unity3d Plugin Project Home https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

Installation Admob Unity

Open your project in the Unity editor.
Navigate to Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package.
Select the AdmobUnityPlugin.unitypackage file.
Import all of the files for the plugins by selecting Import. Make sure to check for any conflicts with files.
Unity Plugin Wiki and Documentation

1.Init Admob Unity Plugin
Create A C# script ,drag the script to a object on scene , add the follow code in the script file

```
    using admob;
    Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");//admob id with format ca-app-pub-279xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx
```

2.Add Admob Banner in Unity App
Here is the minimal code needed to show admob banner.

```
Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0);
```

The AdPosition class specifies where to place the banner. AdSize specifies witch size banner to show

3.Remove Banner
By default, banners are visible. To temporarily hide a banner, call:

```
Admob.Instance().removeBanner();
```